# QueryOver Nhibernate where sum is Greater

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

```
Select * 
from TableA a 
where a.AmountA + a.AmountB > 1
```

I am trying to do the above with the QueryOvery API.

I have already tried

```
QueryOver<TableA>().Where(x => x.AmountA + x.AmountB > 1).
```

This does not work as it returns an error saying that the x is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

This is what I did:

I added a property to my class:

```
public virtual decimal SumX {get{return AmountA + AmountB; } set{return;}}
```

On my Class map I added the following:

```
 Map(x => SumX).Formula("AmountA + AmountB");
```

After that, Nhibernate generated the sql I wanted